# CakePHP - missing files when pushing to Github

Tags: php, git, cakephp, netbeans, github

So I created a Cake project through NetBeans, but when pushing the project to a Github repository using the Git bash I got a large amount of warnings, I can't remember what they were and it doesn't look like the bash keeps logs, but they were something got to do with 'line endings' maybe?

Anyway, the push was somewhat successful, but it seemed to leave out some folders and files. The files and folders that did not appear on the online Git repo are:

the 'nbproject' folder the 'vendors' folder (maybe because it was empty) the 'plugins' folder (also empty)

the 'database.php' file

maybe theres some other files missing too but I haven't spotted them yet. When the repo is cloned to another computer the project works fine once the database.php file is created manually, but I cannot open the project in NetBeans as it doesn not recognise the folder as a NetBeans project! strange.

So my questions are:

1. Has anybody encountered this problem before?
2. Is there a different protocol to pushing these projects to Github?

Comment: Check out the contents of `.gitignore` inside of your project

Comment: So what does your local branch say now about those files/folders?

Comment: Note that Git doesn't track directories, so empty directories are never included.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add those files to your git repository and commit them. The netbeans project looks for a .nbproject file, which should be added to your repository as well.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for putting me on to gitignore, never new what that was all about! deleted the repository and made another one, only this time i chose 'cakePHP' from the gitignore dropdown menu before creating. then when i pushed everything online, all the files/folder went with it!

Thanks

EDIT: except for core.php and database.php

gitignore after selecting cakePHP looks like this,

```
tmp/*
[Cc]onfig/core.php
[Cc]onfig/database.php
app/tmp/*
app/[Cc]onfig/core.php
app/[Cc]onfig/database.php
!empty
```

Comment: Config files should rarely be included in your repository. That way you can have separate settings for your development environment, your staging server, production, ...